# How to add breadcrumbs to any WordPress theme

Tags: themes, breadcrumb

How can I add a breadcrumb trail to the top of every page of my site? I wait to to look like: "You are here: (page name)"

Answer (score 0):

Try a breadcrumbs plugin. [Breadcrumb NavXT](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/) is a popular option I believe.

An alternative solution of is just printing the name of the current page. Here's what such a function might look like in its most basic form:

```
function wpse_87332_nav_identifier() {
    $page_name = get_the_title();
    echo "You are here: " . $page_name; 
}
```

Note that this will only work on single pages (posts, pages, media and custom post types etc.), and you'll have to add some logic to display [titles for archive pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48767/how-to-get-category-and-archive-title).

Comment: is there any other option apart from using plugin?

Comment: I want something like this-  You are here: Home>> Name of menu >> Name of submenu

Comment: There is no built in breadcrumbs function in WordPress, but off course you can implement something yourself, but using a plugin is by far the simplest. I've updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: In response to you second comment, if [breadcrumbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadcrumb_(navigation)) is what you want, and you don't feel like spending the time developing your own breadcrumbs plugin, use any of the ones [readily available](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=breadcrumbs). This functionality is not included in WordPress and there are no shortcuts.

Comment: thank you for your support, I am trying to use the function